# Apache PDFBox - no fields?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

Trying to view all the fields in the following [PDF file](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/updated_IDS.pdf) by traversal, but it is "empty".
Yet if I save to a new file:

```
_pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(_pdfFileName));
_pdfDocument.save(new File(_newFileName));
```

I get a proper copy.

With the following code, fields is an empty list:

```
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = _pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();
```

Are the fields "hidden"? Is there a way to get them? (My end goal is to automate filling out some of them)

Answer (score 2):

There are two major form definition formats for PDFs, **AcroForm** forms and XFA forms.

**AcroForm** forms are specified in the PDF specification ISO 32000-1 and ISO 32000-2 and use PDF syntax.

XFA forms are specified outside the PDF specification. Furthermore, they are specified by Adobe, not by ISO or a similar organisation. XFA form definitions use XML syntax.

Meanwhile the PDF specification ISO 32000-2 has deprecated XFA forms.

Most PDF processors do not support XFA forms, and considering that they meanwhile have been deprecated, there hardly is any motivation to start implement XFA forms in them now.

PDFBox, for example, has only very limited XFA support: It allows you to retrieve the XML document defining XFA forms in a PDF and to set it anew. Otherwise the `PDAcroForm` API only supports **AcroForm** form definitions.

---

The form definition in your example file is a pure XFA definition. Thus, `PDAcroForm.getFields()` won't find any fields in it.